# Using Perl I want to compare two files and how do I keep unique lines from first file, discarding matched and duplicate entries from the second file?

Tags: perl

I have two files.

For example, the content of file #1 is:

```
dynSamp/dgenExp
dynSamp/dgenLod
dynSamp/dgenStm
dynSamp/dgenUpd
dynSamp/dmlnodExp
dynSamp/dmlnodLod
dynSamp/dmlnodStm
dynSamp/dmlnodUpd
dynSamp/dmndynLod
dynSam/dmndynStm
dynSamp/dmndynUpd
sample/genExp
sample/genLod
sample/genStm
sample/genUpd
sample/mlnodExp
sample/mlnodLod
sample/mlnodStm
sample/mlnodUpd
sample/mndynLod
sample/mndynStm
sample/mndynUpd
sample/genLod
dynSamp/dgenLod
dynSamp/dmlnodLod
dynSamp/dmndynLod
sample/mndynLod
sample/mlnodLod
```

And the content of file #2 is:

```
dynSamp/dgenExp
dynSamp/dgenLod
dynSamp/dgenStm
dynSamp/dgenUpd
dynSamp/dmlnodStm
dynSamp/dmndynStm
dynSamp/dthrdsUpd_unix
dynSamp/dthrdsUpd_win
sample/genExp
sample/genLod
sample/genStm
sample/genUpd
sample/mlnodStm
sample/mndynStm
sample/thrdsUpd_unix
sample/thrdsUpd_win
sample/genLod
dynSamp/dgenLod
dynSamp/dmndynStm
dynSamp/dthrdsUpd_win
```

I would like to sort out these two file. The result should be the unique contents of first file minus the unique/duplicate contents of second file.

The following should be all that remains of file #:

```
dynSamp/dmlnodExp
dynSamp/dmlnodLod
dynSamp/dmlnodUpd
dynSamp/dmndynLod
dynSamp/dmndynUpd
sample/mlnodExp
sample/mlnodLod
sample/mlnodUpd
sample/mndynLod
sample/mndynUpd
```

Can anyone please help me in sorting out this? Thanks!

Comment: Could you reduce your example to 5-10 lines, please?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: I suggest you start by showing us your code that reads the files in.

Comment: It wasn't - it was in several lines of code, I just applied code formatting..

Comment: why is `dynSam/dmndynStm,` not present in your output?

Comment: @sarathi, It's surely a typo for `dynSamp/dmndynStm`.

Comment: @sarathi, yeah Iam sorry Its a typo :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want something like this ...

```
dogface@computer ~
$ cat sortit.pl
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;


my $file1 = 'file1';
my $file2 = 'file2';

my %bad;
my %good;

open BAD, "<$file2";
while (<BAD>) {
        chomp;
        $bad{$_} = 1;
}
close BAD;

open GOOD, "<file1";
while( <GOOD> ) {
        chomp;
        next if $bad{$_};
        $good{$_} = 1;
}
close GOOD;

open OUT, ">file3";
foreach my $key ( keys %good ) {
        print OUT $key . "\n";
}
close OUT;

dogface@computer ~
$ cat file1
dynSamp/dgenExp
dynSamp/dgenLod
dynSamp/dgenStm
dynSamp/dgenUpd
dynSamp/dmlnodExp
dynSamp/dmlnodLod
dynSamp/dmlnodStm
dynSamp/dmlnodUpd
dynSamp/dmndynLod
dynSam/dmndynStm
dynSamp/dmndynUpd
sample/genExp
sample/genLod
sample/genStm
sample/genUpd
sample/mlnodExp
sample/mlnodLod
sample/mlnodStm
sample/mlnodUpd
sample/mndynLod
sample/mndynStm
sample/mndynUpd
sample/genLod
dynSamp/dgenLod
dynSamp/dmlnodLod
dynSamp/dmndynLod
sample/mndynLod
sample/mlnodLod

dogface@computer ~
$ cat file2
dynSamp/dgenExp
dynSamp/dgenLod
dynSamp/dgenStm
dynSamp/dgenUpd
dynSamp/dmlnodStm
dynSamp/dmndynStm
dynSamp/dthrdsUpd_unix
dynSamp/dthrdsUpd_win
sample/genExp
sample/genLod
sample/genStm
sample/genUpd
sample/mlnodStm
sample/mndynStm
sample/thrdsUpd_unix
sample/thrdsUpd_win
sample/genLod
dynSamp/dgenLod
dynSamp/dmndynStm
dynSamp/dthrdsUpd_win

dogface@computer ~
$ ./sortit.pl

dogface@computer ~
$ cat file3
sample/mndynLod
dynSamp/dmlnodUpd
dynSamp/dmlnodLod
dynSamp/dmlnodExp
sample/mndynUpd
sample/mlnodUpd
sample/mlnodLod
dynSamp/dmndynLod
dynSamp/dmndynUpd
sample/mlnodExp
dynSam/dmndynStm

dogface@computer ~
$
```

Oh if you want file3 sorted, use the following instead:

```
foreach my $key ( sort keys %good ) {
        print OUT $key . "\n";
}
```

Comment: thanks...this also looks fine but the above mention solution seems to be an optimized one...If you don't mine can you brief the difference between your and the one above?best regards

Comment: Both of our solutions use roughly the same amount of resources, but this solution 1) doesn't check if `open` fails, 2) needlessly uses global variables for file handles, 3) hardcodes the input file names and 4) outputs to a file instead of STDOUT.

Comment: Yes I wanted to focus on using two hashes, using one as a filter and the other as the desired data, and not confuse the OP'er with unrelated implementation details.

Comment: If you want a "short" answer I would suggest asking the perlmonks to golf it.

Answer (score 3):

You didn't ask any question, so I presume you are having problems coming up with an algorithm. Here's one:

1. Open the second file.
2. For each line in the second file,

   1. Create an element in a hash keyed by that line.
3. Open the first file.
4. For each line in the first file,

   1. If the hash has no element keyed by that line,

      1. Create an element in a hash keyed by that line.
      2. Print that line.

This algorithm preserves the order of the records of the first file.

---

Since it's rather trivial to code it, I might as well provide that too.

```
my %skip;
{
   open(my $fh, '<', $ARGV[1])
      or die("Can't open \"$ARGV[1]\": $!\n");
   while (<$fh>) {
      chomp;
      ++$skip{$_};
   }
}

{
   open(my $fh, '<', $ARGV[0])
      or die("Can't open \"$ARGV[0]\": $!\n");
   while (<$fh>) {
      chomp;
      print "$_\n" if !$skip{$_}++;
   }
}
```

Usage:

```
script file1 file2 >file.out
```

Or sorted:

```
script file1 file2 | sort >file.out
```

Comment: Hey I found a bug here....whole operation is working fine but the last line in the first file(what ever it may be ) is found to be adding automatically to the final result...can you please look into this??

Comment: You probably have a bad text file. It should end with a newline and doesn't. I've adjusted the code to compensate.

Answer (score 0):

its a bit straight forward in awk with sort:

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$0];next}{if(!($0 in a))print $0}' temp2 temp | sort -u
```

and i think `dynSam/dmndynStm,` should also be included in your output according to your requirement.

```
> awk 'FNR==NR{a[$0];next}{if(!($0 in a))print $0}' temp2 temp | sort -u
dynSam/dmndynStm,
dynSamp/dmlnodExp,
dynSamp/dmlnodLod,
dynSamp/dmlnodUpd,
dynSamp/dmndynLod,
dynSamp/dmndynUpd,
sample/mlnodExp,
sample/mlnodLod,
sample/mlnodUpd,
sample/mndynLod,
sample/mndynUpd,
>
```